# Making a div with text that overflows scroll

Tags: css, text, scroll

Now I have a span with its overflow hidden like so in HTML and CSS - I'm using it for the twitter post on this website: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/

HTML & inline CSS

```
<span style='width:686px; height:50%; display:block; white-space: nowrap; padding-top:14px; padding-left:10px; overflow:hidden;'></span>
```

Now I need to somehow detect when the div does overflow, and then when it does, allow the text to scroll through with jQuery or something similar.

Any idea how to do these two things?

Comment: have you tried "scroll: auto" (okay it's not standard, but is supported by major browsers)

Comment: @BigMike: scroll? Do you mean `overflow:auto`? (But this is a standard) Do you have a link?

Comment: sorry, I was recalling something but after checking it better I've found out it was totally unrelated. Please disregard my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping the overflowing span with a div element and have the div be overflown:

```
<div id="twitWrap" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <span id="myTwitter">A new Twit appears</span>
</div>
```

This way when you add your new twit to the html you can check if the span element's width is larger than its parent element:

```
if( $("#twitWrap")[0].offsetWidth < $("#myTwitter")[0].offsetWidth) ) ...
```

And then apply any jquery code you would like.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to animate?

Comment: You can use jQuery marquee plugin http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Comment: not sure its exactly what i'm after... so I made a new post about it - feel free to respond now you see my more specific need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001522/scroll-inner-text-through-javascript-jquery-but-only-on-mouse-over-to-a-certain

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish some tricks like placing an ending element:

```
<span style="...">Tweet twweeeet ...
 <span id="endd" style="visibility:hidden"> </span>
</span>
```

then you check if #ender is out of its container width:

```
function toolarge() {
  var ender = $('#endd');
  return ender.offset().left - ender.parent().offset().left > ender.parent().width()
}
```

their might be some adjustements to make like using position() instead of offset() and playing with position:absolute property, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps have an inner container that is set to full width of the content (`overflow:visible`). If this inner container is wider than the outer (`overflow:hidden`) container then you need to scroll. Move the inner container to scroll.